# Prism's INavigationAware methods not fired in TabbedPage when tapping tab icons

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using *Prism.Unity.Forms* nuget version *7.2.0.1347-pre*. I have a tabbed page (named *MainPage*) like below:

```
<TabbedPage ...>
     <pages:page1 /> 
     <pages:page2 /> 
     <pages:page3 /> 
     <pages:page4 /> 
</TabbedPage>
```

In the App.xaml.cs I navigate the starting page like below:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"/{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(Views.Pages.MainPage)}");
```

And in the RegisterTypes method I registered stuff like this:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page1, Page1ViewModel>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page2, Page2ViewModel>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page3, Page3ViewModel>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page4, Page4ViewModel>();
```

And here is one of viewmodels as example:

```
public class Page1ViewModel : INavigationAware
{
    public Page1ViewModel()
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }
}
```

I expect whenever I tap Page1 from tab bar(TabbedPage) the above methods are called but they are not. Why?
Whereas if I switch to another tabs by following command those methods will be fired successfully:

```
await NavigationService.SelectTabAsync(nameof(Page1));
```

I need INavigationAware methods to be called every time a tab is tapped in tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the things work in Prism (afik). You should look at working with `IActiveAware` interfcae and `IsActive` flag - have a look at the [docs](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/working-with-tabbedpages.html). Also, check out one of Dan's (one of Prism main contributors) [ViewModels](https://github.com/dansiegel/MobileCenterDemo/blob/ff12b3318929a39ddcd9b85f1ddf16c227249154/src/TodoDemo/ViewModels/ViewModelBase.cs#L34) and how he's using it. Basically, in your ViewModel you could have this kind of code:

```cs
private void OnIsActiveChanged()
{
    IsActiveChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    if(IsActive)
    {
        OnIsActive();
    }
    else
    {
        OnIsNotActive();
    }
}

protected virtual void OnIsActive() { }

protected virtual void OnIsNotActive() { }
```

Comment: I already tried that interface and the IsActive property is set correctly, but what I want is to distinguish between navigating a tab programmatically and tapping from tab bar. I my in question viewmodel I'm acting according to parameter that is sent to it.

Comment: I don't think there's anything out of the box that you could use. Which means that you would need to create some sort of custom logic, where you have a flag indicating when the programmatic navigation happened. If that flag is not set, it means that the user interacted with the app.

Comment: Yes you're right about that logic and flag, but the problem is the place where the flag 
 is set when tab is tapped. We can set the flag when I navigate programmatically because it's in my control.

Answer (score -1):

Add this behavior to the tabbed page and it should start working.

```
<TabbedPage.Behaviors>
<behaviors:TabbedPageNavigationBehavior />
</TabbedPage.Behaviors>
```

BehaviorBase is in the prism.

```
public class TabbedPageNavigationBehavior : BehaviorBase<TabbedPage>
{
    private Page _currentPage;

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(TabbedPage tabbedPage)
    {
        tabbedPage.CurrentPageChanged += TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(tabbedPage);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(TabbedPage tabbedPage)
    {
        tabbedPage.CurrentPageChanged -= TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(tabbedPage);
    }

    private void TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newPage = AssociatedObject.CurrentPage;

        if (_currentPage != null)
        {
            PageUtilities.OnNavigatedFrom(_currentPage, new NavigationParameters());

            var navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters();
            var navigationParametersInternal = (INavigationParametersInternal)navigationParameters;
            navigationParametersInternal.Add(InternalNavigationParameterKey.NavigationMode, NavigationMode.New);

            PageUtilities.OnNavigatedTo(newPage, navigationParameters);
        }

        _currentPage = newPage;
    }
}
```

Source - https://taubensee.net/sharing-context-between-xamarinforms-tabbedpages-using-prism-and-navigationparameters/

Comment: This triggers OnNavigatedTo 2 times when opening the tab using SelectTabAsync